# Acess context from request in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, template-context

How can we access the `context` passed in template in **method views**?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.method_A, name='first_view'),
    path('method_B', views.method_B, name='second_view'),
]
```

```
def method_A(request):
    context = {"name":"sample"}
    html_template = loader.get_template('some_template.html')
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

Template as

```
<div>
   {{name}}
   <a href="method_B">Redirect</a>
</div>
```

```
def method_B(request):
    # Here how to get context which was present earlier
    context = {"second":"second"}
    html_template = loader.get_template('template_B.html')
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

How we can get context in method based views in django.? So that it can be used in another templates.

Comment: Please show your **urls.py**. Also do you want to pass information between views or just re-used the same context variables in both views?

Comment: @Lewis, basically , I need to access the previous information of template (previous context) so that i can update the context to render in another context. Passing information between views would be good here.

Comment: No, you can’t access the context from a previous view. You’ll need to store the data in some way e.g. in the query string `<a href="method_B?myval=57">Redirect</a>` or in a cookie.

Comment: @Alasdair, passing entire context in query string and then parsing it wont be an efficient way. Can we store context at one place so that it can be accessed.

Comment: The querystring was just an example. You could store it in a cookie as I suggested, or the database, or a cache. It’s up to you how you implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You can store as a `session` variable.

**Views**

```
def method_A(request):
    html_template = loader.get_template('some_template.html')
    request.session['my_context'] = 'Example' #Setting Cookie
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

def method_B(request):
    # Here how to get context which was present earlier
    my_context = request.session.pop('my_context', None) # Getting Cookie
    html_template = loader.get_template('template_B.html')
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```